# iPhone: UIApplicationDelegate and Launch Images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

What is the first method that gets called in the UIApplication Delegate? I have included a launch image in my application, and I would like to get a head start on downloading some data while that screen is still up, before my actual views appear. Should I be looking to place these calls in the delegate, or where is the first place I should think about making these calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

gets called first.

EDIT:
Your Default.png appears for short time when the app is launched. You cannot rely on this short time to do some processing.

You can show your first view with a message that download is in process (with the help of activity indicator view)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the First answer(as **- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application** called at all first), BUT if you want to display your downloaded image on your first view, then implement some delay (BY Timer or something till your image download), and yeah don't forgot to implement an in between screen with activity initializar(otherwise your application will seem like hanged).